# Printer Friendly Pages With a Header on Every Page?

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, printing

I'm working in a J2EE environment with a web app that displays large amounts of tabular data.  We want to be able to print these tables with each page displaying the header and footer.  I understand some browsers support this through the thead,tbody,tfooter tags, but the users are using IE6 only.  A row is normally only one line but on occasion can be two or three (maybe more).

What are my options here?  Is there a quick and easy way that I'm not aware of?  Do I need to some how "calculate" the height of a set of rows?  Or am I stuck doing something static that will hopefully work "most of the time?"

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the right thing in `THEAD` and `TBODY` tags, but try adding the following CSS definitions too:

```
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```