# HTML: IE9 standards mode print TFOOT on every page

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-9, standards

Tables in HTML can have "*footers*":

```
<TABLE>
   <THEAD><TR><TD>Your header goes here</TD></TR></THEAD>
   <TFOOT><TR><TD>Your footer goes here</TD></TR></TFOOT>
   <TBODY>
      <TR><TD>
         Page body in here -- as long as it needs to be
     </TD></TR>
   </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Normally, legacy Internet Explorer would only display the `TFOOT` at the bottom of the entire table. But there was a style that can be applied to `TFOOT` (and `THEAD`) to make it [print at the bottom of each page spanned by the table. From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> `table-footer-group`
>   Object is rendered as [tFoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Table footer is always displayed
>   after all other rows and row groups, and before any bottom captions.
>   The footer is displayed on each page spanned by a table.

Adding `table-footer-group` as a style to `TFOOT` causes it (in Internet Explorer) to print at the bottom of each page spanned by the table:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
   tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
</STYLE>
```

But if IE9 (*release candidate*) is placed into standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

then the `TFOOT` is no longer rendered at the bottom of every page spanning the table, but only at the end of the entire table.

i checked [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html) to see what the proper behavior is, and it's undefined!:

> **table-footer-group (In HTML: TFOOT)**
>   Like 'table-row-group', but for visual
>   formatting, the row group is always
>   displayed after all other rows and row
>   groups and before any bottom captions.
>   Print user agents **may** repeat footer
>   rows on each page spanned by a table.
>   If a table contains multiple elements
>   with 'display: table-footer-group',
>   only the first is rendered as a
>   footer; the others are treated as if
>   they had 'display: table-row-group'.

**Note:** Emphasis added for effect.

Is there a way in IE9 *standards mode* for me to choose to print a `TFOOT` at the bottom of each page spanned by a table?

### Update One

It is interesting to note that `table-footer-group` is a typical default value for `TFOOT` elements, but in previous versions of IE you could choose which behavior you wanted:

- bottom of entire table
- bottom of entire table and every intermediate page

by choosing to include the style.

### Update Two

As it is now i am forcing Internet Explorer to remain in IE8 standards mode with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
   <!--IE8 Standards mode, so that we get the THEAD at the top, and the TFOOT at the bottom, of every page-->
```

### See also

- [Is there a way to get a web page header/footer printed on every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722437/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-web-page-header-footer-printed-on-every-page)
- [MSDN: display Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [W3C CSS2.1: 17.2 The CSS table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)
- [Printer Friendly Pages With a Header on Every Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518163/printer-friendly-pages-with-a-header-on-every-page)
- [table-header-group and table-footer-group in a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048994/table-header-group-and-table-footer-group-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML the behavior was undefined. Browsers could:

- display after the entire table
- display at the bottom of each page.

---

The behavior i was experiencing was in Internet Explorer 9 Release Candidate.

In the final version of Internet Explorer 9 (Version 9.0.8112.1642 RTM) the `TFOOT` appears at the bottom of every printed page, all the time.

In earlier versions of IE you could *choose* between:

- `TFOOT` appearing at the bottom of every page
- `TFOOT` appearing after the table

by manually specifying the `TFOOT` css style:

```
tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
```

Even though `tfoot` already has the display style of `table-footer-group`, **specifically** including it would tell IE you want the TFOOT printed at the bottom of every page. (rather than after the table).

**Not** specifying it (the default behavior) will make IE print the `TFOOT` *after* the entire table.

If you are using IE9, and want to only have a `TFOOT` appear after the whole table has printed, you will have to put Internet Explorer into IE8 standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
   <!--IE8 Standards mode, so that we get the TFOOT after the entire table has printed, not at the bottom of each printed page-->
   ...
```